# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 21

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmd, cgal

## Question Explaination

I am trying to running a program using cgal4.6.1, boost1.58.0, qt4.8.5 on my win32 PC with VS2010 ultimate. But when I build the solutions, there are errors happen as showing below. I've deploy the cgal etc well. I wondering how to solve this problem? I will appreciate for your solutions

## Error Output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: qmat, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/31/2015 4:07:00 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\qmat.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>CustomBuild:
1>  Moc'ing GLWidget.h...
1>  The device is not ready.
1>  Moc'ing medialaxissimplification3d.h...
1>  The device is not ready.
1>  Uic'ing medial_axis.ui...
1>  The device is not ready.
1>  Rcc'ing medial_axis.qrc...
1>  The device is not ready.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 21.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.40
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Error code 23 is not unexpected, it is Windows error ERROR_NOT_READY, "The device is not ready".  Your custom build did not go well, whatever tool you use does not do a fantastic job of giving contextual help.  The error code usually indicates a bad default directory or disconnected drive.  You can see more with SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: @HansPassant I am appreciating for your help and thank you very much. I've struggled it for many days. I will follow your help to find more info about sysinternels' process monitor and try to solve this problem. Thanks!